# Multiple asp:CommandField(s) at the same cell

Tags: asp.net, gridview, commandfield

My asp:GridView has the options to edit / delete rows. I would like those two options to be in the same cell of every row that I have (currently these two options are presented in different cells).

This is the code that I have right now:

```
<asp:CommandField ShowEditButton='True' edittext='edit' canceltext='cancel' updatetext='update'></asp:CommandField>
<asp:CommandField ShowDeleteButton='True' DeleteText='delete' ></asp:CommandField>
```

Any help will be appreciated!!!

Comment: I read your comments on some other answers but I'm still not sure I understand why you can't use an `<asp:TemplateField>` like DaniDev suggests. A TemplateField allows more customization whereas a CommandField just simply auto generates code for you. You can do anything in a TemplateField that you can in a CommandField. You just have to do it manually.

Answer (score 0):

Try     asp:TemplateField

and put both of your options there? I'm not sure if that will work. But have you tried it?

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. Unfortunately when putting my options inside asp:TemplateField, my CommandFiled gets the error: Element 'CommndField' is not a known element.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/11307020)

Comment: @ElGavilan This is an *attempt* at an answer and not (only) a request for clarification. The questions in this answer can be regarded as rhetorical questions. If you think this is a wrong answer or is bad otherwise, you can downvote it. Don't misuse the delete recommendation of the LQPRQ for that.

Answer (score 0):

Try using a template column like this:

```
<asp:GridView ID="grid" runat="server" OnSelectedIndexChanged="grid_SelectedIndexChanged">
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Button id="btnEdit" runat="server" />
                <asp:Button id="btnDelete" runat="server" />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

Then you'll have to add the code for your `grid_SelectedIndexChanged`

```
protected void grid_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

}
```

Comment: I don't want to use this method because my current code gives me the option to edit the column's data inside the gridview itself.

Comment: Understood. Unfortunately that is the price one must pay for using pre-packaged ASP.net controls.
I don't think you'll be able to put them into one column unless you use your own custom code.
Behatzlacha!